# Comparing proportion of categories in samples of different sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Maybe this is a very simple procedure, but I have been trying to find the appropriate method and I am getting confused.

I have data from two different surveys.  In the first survey (s1) there were 100 participants and in the second survey (s2) there were 500.

There were 10 question in each survey that measured the same thing. All questions had the same four possible answers:

- "No, I haven't",
- "I haven't, but I have heard from people who has",
- "I haven't but I know someone personally who has",
- "Yes, I have"

I want to check if, for each of the 10 questions, the proportions of answers are significantly different between the two surveys.

What is the best method to test this? I have tried chi-square, but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Thanks for any help!!